# D3: How to set plots in x axis correctly when x axis are formed by labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm newbie with D3 and I'm trying to set plots in a graphic where x Axis has labels.

I set the points, but not correctly over the line of each x label. You can check it on this image:

[image]

You can find the code in codesandbox:

[image: Edit multiple-scatter-plot]

The file where I define the Scatter Plot is: MultipleScatterPlot.js

What am I doing wrong?

***Fixed: I have fixed my problem using the method padding(1)***

```
  /**
   * Method which serves us to define the scale and range of the graphics
   * @param {*} data
   */
  setScales(data) {
    let xRange = [
      this.state.OFFSET_LEFT,
      this.state.WIDTH - this.state.OFFSET_RIGHT
    ];
    let yRange = [
      this.state.OFFSET_TOP,
      this.state.HEIGHT - this.state.OFFSET_BOTTOM
    ]; // flip order because y-axis origin is upper LEFT

    let xScale = d3
      .scaleBand()
      .domain(
        data.map(d => {
          return d.value_x;
        })
      )
      .range(xRange)
      .padding(1);

    let yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([100, 0])
      .range(yRange); 

      return {
      xScale: xScale,
      yScale: yScale,
      xRange: xRange,
      yRange: yRange
    };
  }
```

Is hire when if we add padding(1) all points are setted to their correspondiente x_label, like you can see now:

[image]

And now, is perfect!!! It's what I want to do!!!

Comment: You're using a band scale, but your elements don't have bandwidth: the x value returned for a band in a band scale is the left hand edge of the band. If you are plotting points, you want the middle of the band, which is what a [scalePoint](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#point-scales) scale does (basically a band scale with the bandwidth set to zero). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41037895/7106086) answer may be useful if you want to keep the band, it also provides a bit more explanation, it might be an appropriate duplicate, though if you disagree I could add an answer.

Comment: Andrew has a good point you're using `scaleBand` for your graph, you might want to consider his answer. Or quick hack, you could set `.padding(1)` on your `xScale`  to set inner and outer padding with same value

Comment: I have fixed muy problem width padding(1). Thank you for your appreacieted help to both of you